# Xcode 5, Your First Mac App tutorial: Can not connect to outlet

Tags: xcode, macos

I am new to XCode and follow the steps in Your First Mac App tutorial.
As tutorial instructs I try to add an outlet for the text field using Control-drag from the text field in the window to the method declaration area in the header file. 
This results in Connection pop-up menu with Connection filed that contains Action instead of Outlet. I can not change Action to Outlet, because field is disabled: 
(https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapOSX/books/RM_YourFirstApp_Mac/Articles/ConfiguringtheWindow.html)

Other ways to connect to outlet? 
[image]

Comment: That's because ui > code are *actions* and code > ui are *outlets*.  Restart the tutorial and persist.

Comment: Downvotes are not helpful.

Comment: Should I restart XCode to solve this problem?

Comment: I don't think that's the problem.  Can you post a screenshot showing what is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, now you've uploaded the screenshot it's clear what the issue is.  You have the implementation (`.m`) file open, when you want the interface file (`.h`) file instead.

From the text of the tutorial:

> Control-drag from the text field in the window to the method
>   declaration area in the interface file.

Note the "interface file" is more commonly known as the "header file".

Comment: Thanks, got that. But how can I bring AppDelegate.h and MainMenu.xib windows side by side to do this "control drag" thing? Windows overlap and when one is open the other one goes out of focus. Is there any way to create /connect outlets/ actions with code using text editor only? Where can I read about this?

Comment: @AntonAshanin You can switch using `Navigate > Open Next Counterpart` (there might be an icon for it on the right window).  I normally write the action declaration in the header file (`- (IBAction)someAction:(id)sender;`) and then control-drag from the control to the *Files Owner* and select the action from the menu that pops up.  There must be more about it at the Apple Developer site.

Answer (score 1):

Go to xib --> File Owner --> Custom Class --> Write the name of the class to which Xib Belongs.

Comment: When I click on FileOwner icon I can't find anywhere Custom Class menu. Where is it?

Comment: on the right toolbar..at the top go to show identity inspector.

Comment: Thanks, found it. Alas, this did not help. Another strange thing is that in Custom Class drop down menu with class names instead of my TrackMix class I get only TrackMixTests. Why is that?

Comment: go to fileower and then go to custom class after that you can get the name of your class..

Answer (score 0):

i dont exactly understand your prob. but if u are working with the storyboard and drag a textfield on the screen u can declarate it in your .h file like this:

```
IBOutlet NSTextField *myTextField;
```

then a little circle should appear beside this. just hold the circle and connect it to the textfield on the storyboard.

Comment: I don't expect that is following the tutorial is it?

Comment: This is for Mac OSX not iOS so your answer should be changed to: IBOutlet NSTextField *myTextField;

Comment: AHHH, didn't see it where for OSX sry.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the outlet in the .h file and control drag from your nib file textfield  to that outlet to connect or you can control drag from your textfield to your file owner which will give the menu and you can choose the outlet.

Comment: I don't expect that is following the tutorial is it?

Comment: there are multiple ways to create the outlet, what you can do is delete the action in header file and control-drag again and choose the iboutlet option instead.

Comment: Yes, and that is how I do it myself, but doing it in a different way to the tutorial the OP is following won't help him.

Comment: it's right to follow the steps in tutorial but the best way to learn something is by making mistakes and correcting them, by trying different approaches you can decide what is the best possible way to do the task.